# WiX variables set in MSI and its custom actions available in the bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.10

We have a MSI that has some custom actions that set some variables/properties, and are looking at building a bootstrapper that bundles/calls this MSI.  Would the bootstrapper have access to the variables set in the MSI after the MSI finishes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented API that will allow to do that.  Maybe it is possible by intercepting/analyzing progress/diagnostic message streams/log files from the MSI, but you do not want to use such a method in production.